# Rewrite - Virtual Directories and Subdomains

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm running Apache2 webserver on linux
My domain is peku33.net
In apache configuration I've set DomainAlias to *.peku33.net

In my public_html directory I have:

```
SomeSite.php
SomeOtherSite.php
SomeotherSiteEtc.php
```

I want to redirect

```
SomeSite.php -> peku33.net/SomeOTHERText/
SomeOtherSite.php -> mysite.peku33.net/SomethingElse/
SomeotherSiteEtc.php -> mysubdomain.peku33.net/Blablabla/Blabla/
```

I also want to disable direct access to theese files (calling http://peku33.net/SomeSite.php will return 304 or 301 code with approperiate Location: )

Thanks for your replays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough, just stick something along the following lines in either a **.htaccess** file in the document-root directory of your sites (not that efficient as Apache will read and parse the file on every request, also assumes directory **Includes** have been permitted in the **httpd.conf** for your sites document root), or preferably in the **Virtualhost** definition within your Apache's **httpd.conf**, or associated included **.conf** :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST)          ^peku33\.net$        [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?SomeOTHERText/     SomeSite.php         [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST)          ^mysite              [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?SomethingElse/     SomeOtherSite.php    [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST)          ^mysubdomaint        [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?Blablabla/Blabla/  SomeotherSiteEtc.php [L]

#Attempt to block direct requests to a .php script, only internally rewritten requests should get through 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}        SomeSite\.php        [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?SomeSite.php       -                    [F,NC]
```

Note:

```
F   = Fail   (Could use G=Gone or R=### instead)
NC  = Not Case-sensitive
L   = Last
^/? = optional leading slash, best to leave in place, as the leading slash is stripped from the URI, when the rule is .htaccess based.
```

The Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation is worth a read if your unclear as to what the above rules do, or if you want something a little more abstract consider the following [post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_4043.html).

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

```
Redirect /SomeSite.php http://peku33.net/SomeOTHERText/
```

You can add `permanent`, `temp`, and `seeother` for 301, 302, and 303 redirects, respectively.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but I want the http://peku33.net/SomeOTHERText/ to display the result of /SomeSite.php